# Responsive datatable or table with pagination using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm looking for some sample code on how to implement a datatable/table with pagination keeping responsive in mind. I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Has anyone had experience with Bootstrap 3 and jQuery Datatables?  Do the 2 play along well?  And with regards to being a responsive datatable? This question isn't related to just Bootstrap and jQuery datatables but it is the only decent datatable that I have worked with.

The reason why I ask is because I need a responsive datatable or normal table with pagination and sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't gone as far as making a "responsive" datatable with bootstrap, but the two certainly can be used together.

Check out this link: http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2 and keep in mind the article is for Bootstrap 2. For Bootstrap 3, you will need to refer to http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration as some class names have changed between Bootstrap 2 and 3. It shouldn't be too difficult from there, if you're familiar enough with Bootstrap, to get a responsive datatable.

Edit: Allan also has some Bootstrap 3 integration files already whipped up [here](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/master/integration/bootstrap/3).

Comment: I'll check it out. Your first link displays a 404 error.

Comment: Its been a while since I've monkeyed around with this stuff, but it appears Alan has updated his site and the datatables plugin quite a bit since then, so here is a new link. There is a comment to consider there, but I'm not sure how true it is. 
http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap